# Identify the set these LEGO elements are from

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

I have a LEGO set without any instructions:

[image]

Which set could it be, how can it be assembled?

Thanks you

Comment: These are random pieces, not a set

Comment: I thought it was a set, thanks for your reply

Comment: No set contains 4 of the rounded 1x2 plates in yellow, at most 2 (https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=35480&in=S&colorID=3&ov=Y)

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve That should be an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

No set listed on bricklink or brickset contains 4 of the rounded 1x2 plates in yellow, at most 2, so this is either no set or it is not listed yet on those sites. Also it's a relatively small amount of bricks (48), too few to amount to a set.

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=35480&in=S&colorID=3&ov=Y

Comment: However, all the pieces shown appear in an even amount:  is it possible that it is a bag of 24 pieces from 2 copies of a set?

Comment: No, that would still mean that there are 2 of the rounded plates, which means only 41386 qualifies and it's easy to see that this set does not contain many of the other pieces...

Answer (score 3):

Looking closely at the picture: Those bricks aren't LEGO at all, they are from some unidentified clone brand. I cannot see any logos on top of the studs (neither LEGO or any other).

Comment: That's a great observation. PIP on top of studs prove your point.